# JMS serializer - Why are new objects not being instantiated through constructor

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

Why are new entities instantiated with null for all values except the data in the json, why is the entity constructor not setting defaults - putting a die() in the constructor never gets executed.

### Update:

*Ok so digging into the code, when no managed entity is found, JMSS will use the doctrine instantiator class to create the entity - its sole job, to create entities without calling the constructor.  Is there a reason for this? this is inside `JMS\Serializer\Construction\UnserializeObjectConstructor`*

---

I've configured the object constructor to use the doctrine object constructor written by JMS, but the same issue happens with and without this.

```
jms_serializer.object_constructor:
    alias: jms_serializer.doctrine_object_constructor
    public: false
```

Existing entities are updated without trouble, however new entities are missing all constructor set defaults.

Under 'fields' element 0 is existing, element 1 is new.

```
array (size=3)
  'id' => int 2
  'name' => string 'Categories' (length=10)
  'fields' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => int 49
          'displayName' => string 'Car Branded' (length=11)
          'type' => string 'checkboxlist' (length=12)
          'required' => boolean false
          'disabled' => boolean false
          'name' => string 'h49' (length=3)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'type' => string 'email' (length=5)
          'name' => string 'field3491' (length=9)
          'displayName' => string 'Email' (length=5)
```

The entity looks like this after deserializing:

```
object(stdClass)[2000]
  public '__CLASS__' => string 'AppBundle\Entity\FormElement' (length=28)
  public 'id' => null
  public 'label' => string 'Email' (length=5)
  public 'type' => string 'email' (length=5)
  public 'defaultValue' => null
  public 'required' => null
  public 'mappedField' => null
  public 'garbageCollection' => null
  public 'sortOrder' => null
  public 'disabled' => null
  public 'uuid' => null
  public 'form' => null
  public 'multiOptions' => null
  public 'filters' => null
  public 'submissions' => null
```

The entity constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->required = false;
    $this->disabled = false;
    $this->garbageCollection = false;
    $this->sortOrder = 0;
    $this->type = 'text';
}
```

And finally this is how im deserializing:

```
$serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');

$entryForm = $serializer->deserialize($json_data, 'AppBundle\Entity\EntryForm', 'json');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is the default ObjectConstructor uses Doctrine's Instantiator, which does not call the class' constructor. To solve this, you can create your own ObjectConstructor that just returns a new instance of the class.

Example:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Serializer;

use JMS\Serializer\Construction\ObjectConstructorInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\DeserializationContext;
use JMS\Serializer\Metadata\ClassMetadata;
use JMS\Serializer\VisitorInterface;

class ObjectConstructor implements ObjectConstructorInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function construct(
        VisitorInterface $visitor,
        ClassMetadata $metadata,
        $data,
        array $type,
        DeserializationContext $context
    ) {
        $className = $metadata->name;

        return new $className();
    }
}
```

If you're using the bundle, just set `jms_serializer.unserialize_object_constructor.class` parameter to that new class. Otherwise in your builder, use the class as your object constructor.

Comment: Can you explain how you set the `jms_serializer.unserialize_object_constructor.class` to the new class?

Comment: He means setting the `jms_serializer.unserialize_object_constructor.class` configuration option to the path of your own implementation of the `ObjectConstructorInterface`, which would be `AppBundle\Serializer\ObjectConstructor` in this example.

Comment: For serializer-bundle ^3.0 overriding the class *parameter* no longer works for me. What works is to override the `jms_serializer.unserialize_object_constructor` *service* pointing it to `class: AppBundle\Serializer\ObjectConstructor`.

Comment: Update for people who will run into this issue: this is enough `jms_serializer.unserialize_object_constructor:
    class: AppBundle\Serializer\UnserializeObjectConstructor` 
No need to add aliasing :
`jms_serializer.object_constructor:
       alias: jms_serializer.doctrine_object_constructor 
       public: false` 
or you will encounter circular reference

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was simply adding this to the jms_serializer config:

```
jms_serializer:
    object_constructors:
        doctrine:
            fallback_strategy: "fallback"
```